# Wearing clothes when husband and child is at home

Tags: husband-wife, clothing

I had some clothing issue I thought that I was wearing the wrong ones when my husband and my 5 year old child is at home so I have listed them below and I have described them please tell me if they are ok

1) sleeveless undershirt ( don’t wear any shirt on a vest )
2) shorts that are above my knee
3) half sleeve shirt
4) small shirt that is above my bellybutton
5) seethrough shirt ( can see my bra )
6) seethrough pant and tight can see my bakini

Please tell me if they are ok to wear in my house when my husband and my 5 year old child are there

Comment: Basically there's a difference between what you may show your husband and what is allowed to show your kid and of course what other people may see of your body/clothes. Simply speaking your husband may be allowed to see anything, while anybody else would have some restrictions, which you should take in consideration before appearing in front of them. Also have in mind that Allah is all seeing, so also consider how you would present yourself. Don't care about voting as long as your question is on-topic (check our [help]).

Answer (score 3):

In the Quran, Surah An-Nur([24:58](https://quran.com/24/58)), Allah says:

> 'O you who have believed, let those whom your right hands possess and
>   those who have not [yet] reached puberty among you ask permission of
>   you [before entering] at three times: before the dawn prayer and when
>   you put aside your clothing [for rest] at noon and after the night
>   prayer. [These are] three times of privacy for you. There is no blame
>   upon you nor upon them beyond these [periods], for they continually
>   circulate among you - some of you, among others. Thus does Allah make
>   clear to you the verses; and Allah is Knowing and Wise.'

We are all aware that once a person reaches puberty, he/she is considered an adult and should be treated as such. For those below that age, the above ayah makes it clear there it parents should teach them the concept of privacy as to instill in them modesty .

Based on the above ayah many scholars including Ibn ‘Ashoor, Ibn Sa’di and Abu Bakr al-Jassaas recommend to cover the awrah of oneself and even small children  so that that will be like second nature to them when they grow up. Children as we know are very impressionable at a young age and their character is greatly formed when young.

Indirectly connected to your question is another important Hadith:

> Narrated Bahz bin Hakim: "My father narrated to me from my
>   grandfather, who said: 'I said: "O Messenger of Allah! Regarding our
>   'Awrah, what of it must we cover and what of it may we leave?" He
>   said: "Protect your 'Awrah except from your wife or what your right
>   hand possesses."' He said: "What about a man with another man?" He
>   said: "If you are able to not let anyone see it, then do so." I said:
>   "What about a man when he is alone?" He said: "***Allah is most deserving
>   of being shy from Him***." (Tirmidhi - [Vol. 5, Book 41, Hadith 2769](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/629900))

Sister, I'd also recommend you to seek the same advise from your mother or elders as they would know your situation better than anyone of us on this forum. The above references are from an Islamic perspective which you can share with them and take advantage from your elder's wisdom.

Salaam!

Answer (score 0):

For your husband it is ok to see you like that, but as far as you see, that you son starts to watch you intentionally, stop wearing that infront of him. Better wear it even now only front of your husband. If your son sees it every day, he will think, it's normal for a woman to run like that and he won't learn modesty. Later it will be hard for him to understand, why women have to cover themselves with hijab.